# Coldfusion/SQL: Element Id is not defined in form

Tags: sql, coldfusion

When I attempt to delete an item in a shopping cart. I get a "Element Id is not defined in form" error.

Where am I going wrong?

I'm using MSSQL 2008 r2, Coldfusion 10.

Summary:

tickets.cfm this is the page that displays the products, also contains a form with hidden values to be passed on to cart_manage.cfm.

cart_manage.cfm is an action page for both tickets.cfm and cartlist.cfm

cartlist.cfm is a page that displays the shopping cart contents.

application.cfm session variables.

**application.cfm**

```
<cfapplication sessionmanagement="yes">
<cfapplication name="cart" clientmanagement="Yes"
sessionmanagement="Yes"
sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,15,0)#"
applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,2,0,0)#">

<cfparam name="session.allowin" default="false">
```

**tickets.cfm**

```
    <cfif NOT IsDefined('SESSION.cart')>
  <cfset SESSION.cart = ArrayNew(1) />
</cfif>
<cfquery datasource="sqltest" name="getTickets">
select *,
       CASE WHEN Friday=1and Saturday=1and Sunday=1
            THEN 'All three days'
            WHEN Friday=0and Saturday=0and Sunday=0
            THEN 'None'
            ELSE
       STUFF(
       case when Friday=1 then ',Friday' else '' end
     + case when Saturday=1 then ',Saturday' else '' end
     + case when Sunday=1 then ',Sunday' else '' end, 1,1,'')
            END WhichDays
from tickets_performances;
</cfquery>

<table width="600" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>How Many Left</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <p> You can only purchase a maximum of two tickets at a time. Having a ticket limit ensures fairness to all those buying tickets. The ticket limit applies per account, billing address, and/or credit card. Please observe the ticket limit as over purchases may be cancelled without notice or warning. </p>
      <cfform action="cart_manage.cfm" name="form" method="post">

  <cfoutput query="getTickets">
      <tr>
        <td>#WhichDays#</td>
        <td>&pound;#price#</td>
        <td>#stock#</td>
        <td><cfinput type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" size="5" class="field" maxlength="1" value="0"/></td>
        <td><cfinput type="hidden" name="id" value="#getTickets.ticket_performanceID#" />
          <cfinput type="hidden" name="item" value="#getTickets.WhichDays#" />
          <cfinput type="hidden" name="price" value="#getTickets.price#" />
          <cfinput type="submit" name="add_button" value="Add to Cart"></td>
      </tr>
  </cfoutput>
      </cfform>

</table>
```

**cart_manage.cfm**

```
<cfset newitem = 0>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(session.cart)#" index="i">
<cfif session.cart[i].itemid EQ #form.id#>
<cfset session.cart[i].quantity = session.cart[i].quantity + #form.quantity#>
<cfset newitem = 1>
<cfbreak>
</cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfif newitem EQ 0>
<cfset temp = arrayAppend(session.cart, structNew())>
<cfset session.cart[arrayLen(session.cart)].itemid = #form.id#>
<cfset session.cart[arrayLen(session.cart)].item = #form.item#>
<cfset session.cart[arrayLen(session.cart)].quantity = #form.quantity#>
<cfset session.cart[arrayLen(session.cart)].price = #form.price#>
<cflocation url="cartlist.cfm">

</cfif>

<cfif IsDefined('FORM.delete_button.y')>
  <cfloop from="#ListLen(FORM.delete_index)#" to="1" index="i" step="-1">
    <cfset ArrayDeleteAt(SESSION.cart, ListGetAt(FORM.delete_index, i))>
  </cfloop>
  <cflocation url="cartlist.cfm">
<cfelseif IsDefined('FORM.update_button.y')>
  <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(SESSION.cart)#" index="i">
    <cfset SESSION.cart[i].quantity = FORM["quantity_" & i] >
  </cfloop>
  <cflocation url="cartlist.cfm">
<cfelseif IsDefined('FORM.checkout_button.y')>
  <cflocation url="checkout.cfm">
</cfif>
  <cflocation url="cartlist.cfm">
```

**cartlist.cfm**

```
<cfset nTotal = 0 />
<cfform action="cart_manage.cfm" method="post">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>
        <table width="100%" class="white">
          <tr>
            <td class="tblehead">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="tblehead">Item</td>
            <td class="tblehead">Price Per Item</td>
            <td class="tblehead">Quantity</td> 
            <td class="tblehead">Price</td>
          </tr>
          <cfoutput>
            <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(SESSION.cart)#" index="i">
              <tr>
                <td height="40" width="40" align="center" class="dkturq">
                  <cfinput type="checkbox" name="delete_index" value="#i#" />
                </td>
                <td height="40" class="dkturq">
                  #SESSION.cart[i].item#
                </td>
                <td height="40" class="dkturq">
                  &pound;#(SESSION.cart[i].price)#
                </td>
                <td height="40" class="dkturq">
                  <cfinput type="text" name="quantity_#i#" value="#SESSION.cart[i].quantity#" size="5" class="field" />
                </td>
                <td height="40" class="dkturq">
                  <cfset nPrice = SESSION.cart[i].quantity * SESSION.cart[i].price />
                  <cfset nTotal = nTotal + nPrice />
                  &pound;#(nPrice)#
                </td>
              </tr>
            </cfloop>
          </cfoutput>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <table width="100%" height="100%" class="white">
          <tr>
            <td class="tblehead">
              Summary
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="dkturq">
              total:
              <cfoutput>&pound;#(nTotal)#</cfoutput>
              <br /><br /><br /><br />
              <a href="clear.cfm">Clear Shopping Cart</a>
                <cfinput type="submit" name="update_button" id="update_button" value="update"  />
               <cfinput type="submit" name="delete_button" id="delete_button" value="delete"  /><br /></a>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</cfform>
```

**CFDUMP of FORM**

[image]

**CFDUMP of Session.cart**

[image]

**Error:**
[image]

**CFDUMP when I press delete**
[image]

Comment: What page does the error occur on? Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Step 1 - cfdump your form and verify that the id element is there.

Comment: @ Dan I get the following error when I add a Cfdump of the form:  Element ITEMID is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.

Comment: @ Scott- " Element ID is undefined in FORM. " is the Coldfusion error.

Comment: when you dump out your `session` is `session.cart[i].itemid` in there?  is this page hit after a form has been posted?

Comment: @ Dan -- I get the from dump if I clear all sessions. Yes the ID is there.

Comment: @CaludiaSasi - Scott was asking you to post the *full* error message, because it includes more details - like the line number where the error occurred. As far as the `cfdump var="#form#"`, you need to place it on the very first line of "cart_manage.cfm". Then try and delete an item again. Doing that will show you that `form.id` does *not* exist (just the error message said) because your two forms are using different field names. `form.id` only exists in the "tickets.cfm" form.

Comment: Thanks Leigh will do in a moment.

Comment: @ Matt, yes it is there, however it's called "Itemid" I've added a photo.

Comment: @CaludiaSasi - That does not look like the dump from "cartlist.cfm" (ie the page throwing the error). Your problem is the two forms contain different field names. Try it again with the right page and look at the dump to see which field name you *should* be using instead of `form.id`.

Comment: Leigh I'm confused, cartlist.cfm uses the action page cartmanage.cfm also.

Comment: I've ran the code from cartlist.cfm, I don't get the form dump, I get the same error: Element ID is undefined in FORM. I'll post an image of the error.

Comment: Re: *cartlist.cfm uses the action page cartmanage.cfm also* Yes, but your two (2) `<form>`'s have **different** field names. That means when you submit the "cartlist.cfm" form, you will see totally different field names than when you submit "tickets.cfm".  The form causing the error is "cartlist.cfm". That is the one you need to test. Also you must put the `cfdump` **on the very first line** of the action page. Otherwise you will never see the dump, because the undefined error will occur first and halt processing ...

Comment: Leigh, I've added a screen dump of the delete.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30698/discussion-between-leigh-and-caludia-sasi)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Leigh, I managed to get it to work.

**(Summary from the chat ..)**

The original problem is pretty much what the error message said. ie Trying to use a form field that does not exist. The cause is "tickets.cfm" and "cartList.cfm" contain different form fields. The form in "cartList.cfm" does not contain a field named `form.id`, hence the error when that form is submitted.  To avoid the error you need to verify the `form.id` exists, with `structKeyExists()` before accessing it.

However, we decided to revise the action page code instead. Also, the "cartList.cfm" form was changed to use `itemID` instead of `index`. Reason being, the `index` can change which might cause the wrong item to be deleted or updated. There is still room for improvement, but here is the jist of the changes:

**cartList.cfm (form fields) **

```
<!--- use itemID's instead of "index" in all form fields --->
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="delete_itemID" value="#SESSION.cart[i].itemid#" />
<cfinput type="text" name="quantity_#SESSION.cart[i].itemid#" value="#SESSION.cart[i].quantity#" size="5" class="field" /><br>
```

**cartManage.cfm**

```
<!--- ADD item to cart ---->
<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "add_button")>
    ... code to add items here ...

<!--- DELETE from cart ---->
<cfelseif structKeyExists(FORM, "delete_button")>
    <!--- 
        Ensure the field exists to prevent errors. Note: A more 
        efficient option is to test the field's existence in the cfelseif 
    --->
    <cfparam name="FORM.delete_itemID" default="">
    <cfloop from="#ArrayLen(SESSION.cart)#" to="1" index="i" step="-1">
        <!--- if this item was marked as "deleted", remove it --->
        <cfif listFind(FORM.delete_itemID, SESSION.cart[i].itemID)>
            <cfset arrayDeleteAt(SESSION.cart, i)>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

<!--- UPDATE item in cart ---->
<cfelseif structKeyExists(FORM, "update_button")>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(SESSION.cart)#" index="i"> 
        <cfset currentItem = session.cart[i]>  
        <!--- Note: For safety, verify the field exists first --->
        <cfset currentItem.quantity = FORM["quantity_" & currentItem.itemID] >
    </cfloop>

</cfif>
```

Comment: (Edit) Hope you do not mind, but I updated your answer with a brief summary of the changes made. So it is easier for others to find the answer. (I also added a few comments about potential improvements). If you do not like the changes, feel free to edit away :)